# Can anyone explain this Regex pattern?

Tags: regex, grep

I've been learning Regex/grep from the BBEdit manual, and it's been smooth sailing except for this part (it's near the end, and unlike previous sections doesn't offer an explanation).

The two big parts I'm having difficulty with are the [^ ] part and the first part ^(.*)

Firstly, is that saying anything but a space? How does it then catch the X. Potter, with a space after the X.?

Secondly, the manual talked about non-greedy qualifiers, used so that it wouldn't match the longest pattern by default and accidentally match your full phrase. How does ^(.*) not match the full line and make it \1? Beginning of line, zero or more occurrences of anything but a carriage return? How does that not catch Junior X. Potter as one pattern? I thought we'd have to use a non-greedy qualifier here, but it seems not.

And lastly, what exactly do spaces do in a regular expression pattern? Do they represent themselves, (I thought you needed \t to do that?) or a simple space (don't need to do  *\space* to escape it).

```
Rearranging Name Lists
You can use grep patterns to transform a list of names in first name first form to last name first order (for a later sorting, for instance). Assume that the names are in the form:
 Junior X. Potter
   Jill Safai
   Dylan Schuyler Goode
   Walter Wang
If you use this search pattern:
 ^(.*) ([^ ]+)$
And this replacement string:
\2, \1
The transformed list becomes:
 Potter, Junior X.
   Safai, Jill
   Goode, Dylan Schuyler
   Wang, Walter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^(.*)` means match anything from the beginning of the line to a space...

`([^ ]+)$` BUT - not just any space, but the particular space that is followed by 1-or-more non-space characters, then the end of the line.  The "non-space characters to the end of the line" will be the second matching group.

So a human would process this in reverse: find the group of non-space characters at the end of the line, "Potter", then you've found the /2 match. Ah-ha, there is the preceding space, then anything before that is the /1 match, "Junior X.".

**Edit**: a space represents itself, it doesn't need to be escaped.  So be careful that you don't insert spaces to prettify your regex - it actually means something.

Answer (score 3):

`[^ ]` means "any character except a space"

`^(.*)` means "From the beginning of the line, a group of all characters"

So, the (.*) captures the first space between "Junior" and "X."

I think the [^ ] keeps the first group from being too greedy. Not completely sure on that.

A space is a character just like any other. \t is generally a tab character.

Comment: `.` usually does not match line-break chars.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I didn't address that question directly.

Answer (score 3):

On the `*` modifier and greediness:

`.*` is only as greedy as it can be. But the regexp wants to succeed, so it will do various things (backtracking, et cetera) to still limit the amount eaten by `*`.

In general, think of `.*` as being: “0 characters, up to the most possible characters that will still allow the rest of the pattern to succeed.”

The difference between Greedy `.*` and Non-greedy `.*?` are demonstrated by:

```
    "A B C D"

    /^(.*) /   → "A B C"
    /^(.*?) /  → "A"
```

Answer (score 2):

The carat (^) symbol is a bit confusing in Regular Expressions, it has two meanings:

1) When used in the beginning of the expression it matches the beginning of line. So

```
 ^a would mean any lines that begin with a
```

2) When used inside character selector it means compliment of the characters (i.e. all but those characters. So:

`[^xyz]` means match a character that is anything EXCEPT x or y or z

`[^a-z]+` means match one or more characters that match anything except all lowercase letters

Hope this helps.

One of the nicer tutorials is at http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Regex.html

Answer (score 2):

In English, your regex `^(.*) ([^ ]+)$` says, "Match every line having exactly some data (or none), followed by a space, followed by 1 or more non-spaces."

*some data* is captured in subpattern 1 `(.*)`
*1 or more non-spaces* is captured in subpattern 2 `([^ ]+)`

This is the data grouped into the matching subpatterns:

```
(Junior X.) (Potter)
(Jill) (Safai)
(Dylan Schuyler) (Goode)
(Walter) (Wang)
```

As to your questions:

1. Yes, `[^ ]` matches anything but a space character. It is not matching "X. Potter", you can see from the transformation that "Junior X." is matching subpattern 1, whereas "Potter" matches subpattern 2.
2. Using `^` and `$` means you are matching an entire line (`^` indicating the beginning of a line, and `$` indicating the end). The first pattern `(.*)` *is* greedy, but the rest of your regex states that you must have a space and it must end with at least one non-space character so `(.*)` matches as much as it can while still satisfying the conditions of the full regex.